# On click not working in responsive menu Bootstrap in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, menu

I am using bootstrap and react js.

if i use this code in destop view its working fine but i am using this in mobile view onclick function not working

here is my code

JSX CODE

```
<div className="container main-menu">
                <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-between d-flex">
                    <div id="logo">
                      <a href="/"><img src="/public/img/logo.png" alt="" title="" className="logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <nav id="nav-menu-container">
                      <ul className="nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Become A member</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"  className="btnlogin"  onClick={() => { alert("test"); this.setState({showLoginModal: true});$('#loginModal').modal('show'); $('.eazyforgot').fadeOut('fast');}}>Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"  className="btnlogin"  onClick={this.testing}>TEST</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </nav>                     
                </div>
              </div>
```

Here is my function

```js
testing(){
  alert("de mo");
}
```

i used both methods but not working both methods

https://ibb.co/m4pv3K3  'mobile view screen shot no errror comming in console'

https://ibb.co/RS39Rxc 'here is destop view screen capture '

anyone know please help to solve this error.

thanks

Comment: Do not use jQuery with React. You should instead use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) or [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)